# SQL Server 2008 missing thesaurus xml and ftdata folder

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search, thesaurus

I've recently installed SQL Server 2008, and I've tried the full text search and now I need to use the thesaurus for synonymous but I can't find any xmq and the ftdata folder which I read should contain the xml files...thank you!!!

Comment: Have you checked out the appropriate version (for SQL Server **2008** or newer) of [Configure and Manage Thesaurus Files for Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491.aspx) on MSDN?

Comment: Or did you by any chance install the SQL Server 2008 **Express** edition? As far as I know, only the Express **with advanced services** version support full-text search

Comment: i checked your link many times, and the full text search is supported, infact i created a full text index and i can query using  contains and freetext

Comment: infact in the link he says "The default location of the thesaurus files is:
<SQL_Server_data_files_path>\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\FTDATA\" in my case i don't have such folder

Comment: no anything different... my path is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL

Comment: i've installed sql management studio once again but the ftdata doesn't appear

Comment: even if i create the folder and put into the thesaurus it doesn't works...and i don't know why...if i do EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_load_thesaurus_file 1040 it doesn't return an error...where the f... is the thesaurus???

Comment: Is there any chance you have *multiple instances* of various versions on your system? That folder you mentioned is from a **2008 R2** version - maybe you've installed the **2008 R2 Express** without FTS support and you're trying to get a thesaurus into that non-FTS enabled instance?

Comment: yes i installed 2008 R2 Express then i installed sql management studio, i don't understand if i should or not have that folder because when i use full text queries they works such like SELECT * FROM Libri WHERE CONTAINS(Riassunto, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, fare)'); but where shoud i place the thesaurus xml???
when i do EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_load_thesaurus_file 1040 return success, maybe is because the database is not on my local pc?

Comment: Which ***version*** of SQL Server 2008 R2 Express did you use? There are multiple versions - only the **Express With Advanced Services** version include the fulltext search support!

Comment: i downloaded the  SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Service Pack2, BUT if there is not full text support...why am i doing full text queries? i'm asking if maybe because i'm connecting with a remote database i must locate the thesaurus not on my local path

Comment: You must download one of those two files: `SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe` or `SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe` - did you do that?

Comment: no...i downloaded the SQLEXPR_x64_ITA.exe but...i'm asking...since i'm connected with a remote database...maybe the path of the thesaurus is not the one on my local pc??? and...why i am i doing full text queries if mine version does not support????

Comment: and i repeat if i do EXEC sys.sp_fulltext_load_thesaurus_file 1040
it return success...

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue. The documentation Path didn't work. The following path worked for me.
C:\SQLData\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\FTData